# Accessing a struct without the struct being global

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've got a struct called members which contains a bunch of char arrays and integers. The struct has been declared in Header.h and defined it by "struct members pt" in source.c, inside main. From here a for-loop is being runned 5 times and adding variables to the character arrays and ints in `pt[x]`.
Now I need to be able to access this from a function called `void search(int a);` (Should probably not be a void since I want it to return a value. But I'll fix that later)
What void search is supposed to do is basicly

```
int willReturn[10];
int b = 0;
for(int x = 0; x<a; x++)
{
    if(pt[x].hasPayed == 0)
    {
        willReturn[b] = x;
        b++;
    }
}
```

There might be something wrong about that code, but the thing that I need to know is how I can access `pt[x].hasPayed`.
Any ideas?
I do not want to use any global variables.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is `pt` ? what is `a` ? Show your code instead of explaining it over 6 lines.

Comment: If `pt` isn't global you have to pass ist as a parameter of search, e.g. `search(int a, struct members pt[] )`

Answer (score 1):

Below sample code might help you.

**header.h**

```
struct members {
    int hasPayed;
};
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main.h"

typedef struct members MEMBERS;

void print_member(MEMBERS *pt) {
    int i;
    for(i =0 ; i< 10; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d\n",pt[i].hasPayed);
    }

}

void main () {
    MEMBERS pt[10];
    int i;
    for(i =0 ; i< 10; i++)
    {
        pt[i].hasPayed= i;
    }
    print_member(pt);
}
```

Instead of print_member code your search logic.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a pointer to `pt` as a paraamter to search. e.g `void search(int a, struct members *pt)`.

Comment: How do I call the function search when I've got the struct as a parameter?

Comment: `search(a, &pt[0])`. How much C do you actually know?

Comment: Thank you. Obviously, I'm just starting up with C, so I don't know very much yet. I'm using the K&R book to learn. However, I couldn't find anything about this in the book.

Comment: This gives me the following LNK error, Error LNK2005: _main already defined in Header.obj and Error 4 LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: @user3194111 you have two functions called main. Possibly you have them defined in Header.h. You should only have main in one place

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I had tried to include source.c in header.c.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you don't want to pass pointers. Place `pt` in a function as a static variable.

```
struct members** ____get_pt(){
    static struct members pt[ /* size */ ];
    /*
        or for dynamical size,
    static struct members* pt;
    */
    return &pt;
}
// Define a macro for convenience, above where you want to use 'pt'.
#define PT (*____get_pt())
```

Then you can use `PT[x].hasPayed` everywhere, without global variables.

However, this could do not improve your code ...

Comment: Where am I meant to put that code? Should I change the declaration of the struct members to what you wrote?

Comment: Identifiers starting with `__` are supposed to be reserved for the implementation